# svn and rails migration files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svn, migration

I am working on a rails project using svn. I generated a migration file and modified a couple of existing files. When I commit my changes, svn only commits the updates on the existing files, and the schema.rb but my newly migration file is not commited. Does anyone know why? I am new to svn and I commit using the svn commmit -m "message"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [svn add](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re01.html) first to add the new file(s) to the repository.